# Cocos2d - Move sprite in curved path

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I am creating a Catapult game in Cocos2d in which the catapult is at the bottom center of the screen and we throw stones on the objects falling from the top of the screen. I tried using Bezier curves for this purpose but problem is that I am not able to calculate control points for drawing bezier curve. I need to move sprite of the stone on a curved path when released from the catapult.
Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve it?
Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Are you following any tutorial? If not, then please check this link:http://www.raywenderlich.com/4756/how-to-make-a-catapult-shooting-game-with-cocos2d-and-box2d-part-1
In this tutorial they have used physics simulation for throwing nuts.

Comment: Hi, they are using box2d but I am working in pure cocos2d. I am not following any tutorial and I could not find any. Can't I move a sprite on a curved path in cocos2d?

Comment: Yes,you can move your sprite in Curved. But for that you have to do lots of manual work, like on what speed it will move in which scenario and lots other.

Comment: I suggest you to use physics in your game and there is pretty awesome tutorial on raywerderlich.com , i have given you that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't use physics for that?

use box2D is integrate with cocos2D, config the world, gravity, and physics budies,so.. the effect of catapult is automatic when you shot a bullet.

Comment: You are absolutely right but what if I want to implement it without box2D? Can you please help?

Comment: if you want do that without box2d, you can calculate the parabolic movement manually, maybe with fake data of velocity an gravity, you can find the math formulas to calculate that on google.